# Where do Subsonic classes go in an ASP.NET MVC Project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subsonic

I've built ASP.NET webform projects in the past, and when generating Subsonic classes, the teams I have been on have put our Business Layer/DAL objects into a Project.Framework project.

Would that still be a recommended structure, or should the Subsonic classes go directly into the /Model folder within the MVC web project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't go in the Model folder (I think the Model folder should just be used for a Class that is made only for the view and wont be used in the rest of the app).

It should go into a separate assembly Maybe **Project.Core** or **Project.Data**

Comment: So what is the relationship between the classes in the model folder and the Subsonic objects in the other project? Is the model just a wrapper for the Subsonic object?

Comment: If you choose to use the model as a ViewModel, the model object is designed to match your view perfectly, with any data the view will ever need. However, a ViewModel designed this way is a poor domain model. Let your Controller talk to a ViewModel, the ViewModel to DomainModel (a SubSonic class)

Answer (score 0):

I would not put the Subsonic classes directly in the MVC project.  Since you didn't with ASP.NET, there is no reason to change now.

I wouldn't even leave the Controllers in the MVC web project.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* put them in Model, and move them to their own project later, but its not really any more work to just put them in their own project now, so I would just do that.